# Reading assembly, jump and compare statements

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm studying for a retake and I'm having problems reading assembly. Question:

Starting with C code of the form

```
1 int test(int x, int y) {
2   int val = ;
3   if ( ) {
4     if ( )
5       val = ;
6     else
7       val = ;
8   } else if ( )
9     val = ;
10  return val;
11}
```

gcc generates the following assembly code:
x at %ebp+8, y at %ebp+12

```
1 movl 8(%ebp), %eax
2 movl 12(%ebp), %edx
3 cmpl $-3, %eax
4 jge .L2
5 cmpl %edx, %eax
6 jle .L3
7 imull %edx, %eax
8 jmp .L4
9 .L3:
10 leal (%edx,%eax), %eax
11 jmp .L4
12 .L2:
Section 3.6 Control 197
13 cmpl $2, %eax
14 jg .L5
15 xorl %edx, %eax
16 jmp .L4
17 .L5:
18 subl %edx, %eax
19 .L4:
```

Fill in the missing expressions in the C code. To make the code fit into the
C code template, you will need to undo some of the reordering of computations
done by gcc.

So I tried this, and I though it would be:

```
int val = x+y
if -3>x
    if 2>x
       val = x^y
    else 
       val = x*y
else if y<x
    val = x-y
```

It compares -3 > x and then it jumps to L2, so I thought that's where we continue (and everytime it jumps, that's where I continued reading). However, it just continues reading it from top to bottom (why?).
Next, when -3 > x, I assumed 2 > x, but now they're turning it around in x>2. Yet, it still is y < x and not x < y. 
So I basically don't get why my entire order of reading the code is wrong, and why they sometimes compare the second argument with the first, and sometimes the other way around. The correct answer is:

```
int val = x^y
if x<-3
    if y<x
      val = x*y
    else
      val = x+y
else if x>2
    val = x-y
```

Comment: You do know that `-3>x` and `x<-3` are the same, right? Also, you can write `if (x) foo else bar` as `if (!x) bar else foo` and those are again equivalent. You did mess up the nesting though.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm confused, because you read it from left to right at -3>x and y<x but from right to left when x>2.

Comment: The `cmpl $-3, %eax` does internally `tmp = eax - -3`, `jge` is when SF=OF, which doesn't say much even to me, but mnemonics abbreviation means "greater/equal than", so when eax is >= -3, then the jump to L2 is taken. When eax < -3, code skips the `jge` and continues on next line. Which is what correct answer has. The AT&T syntax has these operands in reversed order, in Intel syntax the `cmp a1,a2` is `a1-a2` (and "greater/equal" is meant for `a1`), in AT&T syntax the second argument is what follows the `Jcc` abbreviation (greater/equal than).

Answer (score 4):

Most C implementations push arguments on the stack last first, and x86 stacks grow downward. From this:

```
1 movl 8(%ebp), %eax
2 movl 12(%ebp), %edx
```

we can verfiy `edx` holds the word pushed first because it has the higher address. So it's `y`. And `eax` is `x`.

This comparison is `x` ? `-3`. Note the reversal of arguments due to AT&T assembly conventions.

```
3 cmpl $-3, %eax
```

So here we jump to `L2` if `x >= -3`.

```
4 jge .L2
```

Similarly, here we jump if `x <= y`

```
5 cmpl %edx, %eax
6 jle .L3
```

Here we compute a `returnValue = x * y` and jump to the end. Note the compiler has determined that `x` is no longer needed, so it can use the `eax` register for the return value starting here.

```
7 imull %edx, %eax
8 jmp .L4
```

Here we are computing `returnValue = x + y`.

```
9 .L3:
10 leal (%edx,%eax), %eax
11 jmp .L4
```

Here we are jumping if `x > 2`.

```
12 .L2:
13 cmpl $2, %eax
14 jg .L5
```

Here we compute `returnValue = x ^ y`.

```
15 xorl %edx, %eax
16 jmp .L4
```

Here we have `returnValue = x - y`.

```
17 .L5:
18 subl %edx, %eax
19 .L4:
```

Translate this into C that uses gotos as an intermediate step:

```
if (x >= -3) goto L2;
  if (x <= y) goto L3;
    val = x * y;
  goto L4
    L3: val = x + y;
  goto L4
L2: if (x > 2) goto L5;
  val = x ^ y;
goto L4
L5: val = x - y;
L4: return val;
```

Note that most compilers seeing `if (x > y) x *= 3; else y -= 4;` will reverse the sense of the comparison and produce the assembly-level logic

```
if (x <= y) goto L1;
  x *= 3;
goto L2;
  L1: y -= 4;
L2:
```

Using this convention to re-arrange the above, we'd get:

```
int test(int x, int y) {
  int val = x; // Compiler uses eax for both x and return
  if (x < -3) {
    if (x > y)
      val = x * y;
    else
      val = x + y;
  } else {
    if (x <= 2)
      val = x ^ y;
    else
      val = x - y;
  }
  return val;
}
```

The last `else` clause is missing from the provided original C. Our only choice is to infer that the original code put `x-y` in `val` initially, and the compiler did an optimization so the value isn't computed unless its actually returned:

```
int test(int x, int y) {
  int val = x - y; // Compiler doesn't compute x-y unless it's returned!
  if (x < -3) {
    if (x > y)
      val = x * y;
    else
      val = x + y;
  } else if (x <= 2)
    val = x ^ y;
  return val;
}
```